Does vacuum polarization strengthen or weaken the electric field emitted from a proton?
I’m currently reading Rafelski and Muller’s The Structured Vacuum, and I’m a little confused by something they’re saying. I wouldn’t exactly call this a pop-physics book, but it’s pop-ish, so it’s very possible they’re making a mistake.
On pages 35-36, they state that in contrast to a dielectric medium, vacuum polarization strengthens the electric field of a positively charged particle in a vacuum. Meanwhile, Wikipedia, which says that vacuum polarization weakens the electric field of an electron. I’m having a hard time reconciling these statements, since it would seem that either both should be strengthened or both should be weakened. I think that perhaps Rafelski and Muller have made a mistake? But they state this has been empirically confirmed using a muonic helium ion. If they are correct, why would the electric field of an electron be weakened, while that of a proton be strengthened?
I am a mathematician, not a physicist, so I’m not exactly fluent in quantum electrodynamics. I’m just trying to understand one point in a well-written book that I’m greatly enjoying.

I think they are just mistaken. Vacuum polarisation weakens, which means that for the same charges that you use to study, if they are very far away, then you observe a charge strength that is weaker than when you put them close together. They should be meaning that the electric field near to a charge gets stronger than expected. And that the muonic Helium also shows a slightly stronger charge than expected, stronger E fields involved, etc. Both electron and proton will be affected in the same way; both weakened or both strengthened.

Ahhh ok I see the problem now. They were talking about the electric field very near the charge. Thank you!
